# How to send values as json in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send username and password in json format but I am not sure I am doing it in right way. I am still new to angular.

```
myApp.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
    {

    $scope.email = "" ;
    $scope.password = "" ;

    $scope.loginForm = function(){
            alert("login controller called");
            console.log($scope.email);
            console.log($scope.password);
            var encodedString = 'email=' +
                    encodeURIComponent($scope.email) +
                    '&password=' +
                    encodeURIComponent($scope.password);
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url: 'rs/loginResource',
                data: encodedString,
                headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
            });
        };
    }]);
```

When I see in the header post using firefox, the username and password are shown as plain parameters rather than in json format. Right now I am using encodeURIComponent but I want to send it as json. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a query string to send the data with a POST. Nor do you need to specify the content type, Angular will do that for you.

You can use the `post()` shortcut method to send the data:

```
var data = { email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password };
var url = 'rs/loginResource';
$http.post(url, data);
```